# Comparing two collections of data and update the ones that are missing to deleted

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have this form:
[image]

And I have prepopulated 3 emails. Then I decide to remove one email and when I click update I send new collection of emails to API.

How can I update field IsDeleted to the ones in database, where they are no longer in new collection.

Basically when I remove from front end email, I want for those removed to be correspondingly updated in db.

My approach would be:
Get collection of emails for current Contract by Id, then compare to the new collection from front end. The email Ids that are missing then update field IsDeleted to true. But that would be foreach inside of foreach which is O(N2) notation. Is there any simple way with linq?

Answer (score 1):

While you are asking for a Linq solution - You can use [System.Linq.Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
var oldList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var newList = new List<string> { "A", "C" };

var deletedValues = oldList.Except(newList ); // deletedValues = { "B" }
```

After that you can iterate over the `deletedValues` and set your `IsDeleted = true;`

---

According to the [Reference Source - Enumerable.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/e289e6c98881b2b8.html) the following code will be executed.

> ```
> static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
> {
>     Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
>     foreach (TSource element in second) 
>         set.Add(element);
>     foreach (TSource element in first)
>         if (set.Add(element))
>             yield return element;
> }
> ```

---

*But I must admit I can't tell you about the O-notation, because the `set.Add()` will do a lot stuff under the hood. Maybe some one can help me out with that in the comments.*